# Help understanding this simple probability question?

Tags: probability

Suppose you have $20$ objects. $5$ are randomly assigned type $A$. $15$ are randomly assigned type $B$. What is the probability of picking an object of type A given it is of type B? Intuitively, I think the answer is still just $P(A) = 1/4$, but how would I show this formally? Moreover, would the answer remain the same even in more general cases (i.e $K$ objects, $a$ of type $A$, $b$ of type $B$)?.

Answer (score 1):

We have by conditional probability

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Given that $5$ objects are randomly assigned to $A$ and $15$ are randomly assigned to $B$. Because $A$ and $B$ are independent *if and only if* each object is distinct, then we have

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(B)}=P(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

The given wording is unclear, but it sounds like the two random assignments are assumed to be [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). Your conclusion follows immediately from the definition of independence.

If the assignments are not assumed to be independent, then there's not enough information to compute $P(A|B)$.